# Cannot conect FTP using ftp_connect()

Tags: php

I'm Trying connect to ftp on my server using ftp_connet.

1.- I have ftp running in my server and I have de users.

This is my code,

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('192.168.0.10') or die ("Cannot connect to host");
```

This is my server response

> Cannot connect to host

Sorry for my bad english!!

Comment: using windows or linux?

Comment: I'm Using linux (Debian)

Comment: What port is the ftp server running on?

Comment: the port is 21, but i was tried this form `ftp_connect('192.168.0.10',21)` and does not work

Comment: Can you telnet on the service? Like with `telnet 192.168.0.10 21` on the machine running the php script? If you cannot, fix the problem on the ftp server. If you can, does a `var_dump(error_get_last());` bring any more details? PHP's FTP functions regrettably does not have any error handling functions.